# Linux Service running Python script does not update SQL database

Tags: python, sql, linux, sqlite

I have a python script that scans a stock market for transactions and saves them in the SQL database. The script works on its own if I run it directly `python3 fetchTradesLuno24Hours.py` and this updates the database. However, if I run it as a service it stops updating the database. If I run `systemctl status lunoDatabase.service` it shows that service successfully run. The service is triggered by `lunoDatabase.timer` that runs it every several hours. If I run `systemctl status lunoDatabase.timer` or `systemctl list-timers` I see that the timer works and the script is triggered successfully. The service reports that the python script run-time is as expected (around 6 minutes) and the code exited successfully.
Before I tried running python script in the infinite loop and that worked fine and the database was updated correctly from the service. When I added timer it stopped updating the database. I would like the service to update the SQL database and to be trigger by the timer. How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you considered setting up a cron job as specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799023/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-every-10-minutes) (change the cron schedule expression to something like `0 */6 * * *` to run the script every 6 hours or according to your needs)? Notice that you'd need to assign the relevant executable permissions to your script (e.g. chmod u+x /path/to/script.py) ?

Comment: Hi @DanielOcando! Thank you for your response! I managed to fix it. The problem was in the path to the database. I used a local reference path however I should have used an absolute path like `/home/user/bot/transactions.db`. I check your link anyway, maybe that's an easier solution for me. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm very glad that you were able to find a solution of your issue!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the python script. Since I address the python file from the root folder, I should have specified the absolute path the database in `database.py`.

`db = sqlite3.connect('home/user/bot/transactions.db')`

and not

`db = sqlite3.connect('transactions.db')`

Thank you, everyone!